# Can I wrap my application with both a redux provider and an apollo provider?

Tags: react-redux, react-apollo

Can I wrap my application with both a  from `'react-redux'` and an  from `'react-apollo'` or should I choose one or the other?

Several examples I have read on using Apollo for optimistic UI contrast it to creating the same result in redux and how much work that would be.

I'm already using redux and redux-saga in an application and am considering whether I should use the Apollo client for more things than for just making requests.

Here is a code example of what I am doing:

```
return (
    <ApolloProvider client={client}>
        <Provider store={store}>
            <ConnectedRouter history={history}>
                <ScrollToTop>
                    <App />
                </ScrollToTop>
            </ConnectedRouter>
        </Provider>
    </ApolloProvider>
);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're wrapping router provider, too - theme, contexts ... nothing wrong with multiple providers ;)

[Local state](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/essentials/local-state.html) can be used instead redux for some shared app state/data/logic (resolvers) but redux can still have an advantage in many cases.

Comment: Apollo's approach to local state entails a bunch of boilerplate without bringing a lot to the table. Admittedly, Redux is heavyweight too but it's more robust, has time travel and a great suite of debugging tools.